# Is it possible to find tool and die set for my forge?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I am on day 57 and almost visited every place of interest. The forge in 7 days to die require 3 items i.e anvil, callipers and tool and die set. Anvil is easy to make and i found callipers in working stiff crates. Tool and die set is no where to be found. Googling for the solution just gives some random comments on random forum which are different for different versions. I am currently playing alpha 15.

Comment: I know that I was able to find them on the console version of the game. It took me a very long time. I'm past 60+ days but I want to say I found them before that. I believe searching a car is where I found them. Try getting your scavenger level up.  I'm not sure but I think you find better stuff with a higher level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, ask yourself if this is an issue for you. "Tool and Die" set so far (A15) required only for rocket launcher ammo production.

Second of all, you have to check Trader from time to time. Trader is most reliable source of such items.

And last, well obviously, loot more of specific containers. Consult this page for more information: http://www.7daysdb.com/item/tool-die-set, it says:

- Working Stiffs Crate
- Normal cars
- Damaged cars
- Miner's Chests and on the Zombie Miner ([1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/294358/171544))

Comment: I wanna find tool and die set to craft some rocket launcher ammo.

Comment: @RishabhSharma, ah, ok. Then you'd better to ride bike to some distant (if it MP, in SP any non looted) city with Working Tool shop and loot it. I was able to get Tool and Die set even before Callipers on my run.

Comment: I play in a populated server. I guess this makes it even harder to find them. Most of the building are already looted and the building that aren't looted have useless junk in them.

Comment: @RishabhSharma, on the other side Cars are numerous. Especially in Industrial biome. And they are more easy to locate and loot from

Comment: @RishabhSharma Looted containers respawn after a certain period of time set by the server (Loot Respawn Time) so don't despair! It's also possible you're on a server with a low Loot Abundance setting. Check [the server settings](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Game_Settings) listed on the right hand side of the server list.

Answer (score 3):

This ended up being too long for a comment, so here is some more information on the loot locations for the Tool Set and Die, obtained from the data files, in version 15.1.

The Tool Set and Die can be found in the Working Stiffs crates, with a 67% probability and the `rareTools` loot group with a 9% probability.

Rare Tools can also be found in Working Stiffs crates, or where normal Tools are found (though never more than one in a loot box.).  They can also be obtained from lumberjacks.

Normal Tools can be found on Zombie Bikers, Zombie Farmers, and Zombie Utility Workers.  They can also be found in the `automotive-tools-junk` loot group (21% chance) and the `minerloot` loot group.

Automotive junk is only found in cars, currently.

The miner loot can be found in Miner's Chests and on the Zombie Miner.

Please note that all of this is subject to change with every patch, at the whim of the devs, but hope it helps.

Also note that certain containers, like cars, will reveal different items depending on what tool is used to harvest from them.  The item you are looking for, however, is a drop from the cars, and not from the harvest.

Comment: Nice addition about Miners in A15.1. Since my answer was marked, I append this to it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you can increase the chance a trader might have it in their [Secret Stash](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Traders) by leveling up the [Secret Stash perk](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Secret_Stash_(Perk)). Remember when talking to the trader their Secret Stash items *do not* show up in All. You must check them separately.

I suspect (though I cannot confirm) you could also find it in a [Supply Crate](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Supply_Crate) from an [air drop](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Game_Settings#Air_Drops) if you're playing with those turned on. They often contain schematics, ammo, medical supplies, and uncraftable items like beakers. Listen for the sound of an airplane, look for an orange flare, and (if the server has it on) a bright orange marker on your compass.

Finally, if you're on a server using the [Economy Plugin](http://www.servermanager.ca/7-days-to-die-economy-plugin/)
 you can often buy it with zCoins. I personally feel this detracts from the game, but I won't judge you -- much -- for using it. :)